# How to scrape casenet using Scrapy formRequest?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to scraper this site: https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/searchCases.do?searchType=name

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Challenge6.items import Challenge6Item

class CasenetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "casenet"
    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            "https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name"
        ]
        Rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse )

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            inputVO.lastName: 'smith',
            inputVO.firstName: 'fred',
            inputVO.yearFiled: 2010,
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url="https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name", formdata=data, callback=self.parse_pages)
        casenet_row = Selector(response).xpath('//tr[@align="left"]')

    def parse_pages(self, response):
        for row in casenet_row:
            if "Part Name" not in row or "Address on File" not in row:
                item = Challenge6Item()
                item['name'] = quote.xpath('div[@class="tags"]/a[@class="tag"]/text()').extract()
                yield item
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> /var/www/html/challenge6/Challenge6/Challenge6/spiders/casenet_crawler.py:3:
>   ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is
>   deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead   from scrapy.contrib.spiders
>   import Rule 2018-11-14 17:47:54 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1
>   started (bot: Challenge6) 2018-11-14 17:47:54 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO:
>   Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1,
>   w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017,
>   14:50:18) - [GCC 5.4.0 20160609], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14
>   Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform
>   Linux-4.4.0-1066-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2018-11-14
>   17:47:54 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
>   {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Challenge6.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':
>   ['Challenge6.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME':
>   'Challenge6'} 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled
>   extensions: ['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats'] 2018-11-14 17:47:55
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2018-11-14
>   17:47:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2018-11-14 17:47:55
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2018-11-14
>   17:47:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2018-11-14 17:47:55
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2018-11-14 17:47:55
>   [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:6023 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying https://www.courts.mo.gov/robots.txt> (failed 1 times):
>   [] 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry]
>   DEBUG: Retrying https://www.courts.mo.gov/robots.txt> (failed 2
>   times): [] 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry]
>   DEBUG: Gave up retrying https://www.courts.mo.gov/robots.txt>
>   (failed 3 times): [] 2018-11-14 17:47:55
>   [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading https://www.courts.mo.gov/robots.txt>:
>   [] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py",
>   line 43, in process_request
>       defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider))) ResponseNeverReceived:
>   [] 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry]
>   DEBUG: Retrying https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name>
>   (failed 1 times): [] 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry]
>   DEBUG: Retrying https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name>
>   (failed 2 times): [] 2018-11-14 17:47:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry]
>   DEBUG: Gave up retrying https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name>
>   (failed 3 times): [] 2018-11-14 17:47:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error
>   downloading https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py",
>   line 43, in process_request
>       defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider))) ResponseNeverReceived:
>   [] 2018-11-14 17:47:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing
>   spider (finished) 2018-11-14 17:47:56 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO:
>   Dumping Scrapy stats: {'downloader/exception_count': 6, 
>   'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived':
>   6,  'downloader/request_bytes': 1455,  'downloader/request_count': 6, 
>   'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,  'finish_reason':
>   'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 14, 23, 47,
>   56, 195277),  'log_count/DEBUG': 7,  'log_count/ERROR': 2, 
>   'log_count/INFO': 7,  'memusage/max': 52514816,  'memusage/startup':
>   52514816,  'retry/count': 4,  'retry/max_reached': 2, 
>   'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 4, 
>   'scheduler/dequeued': 3,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3, 
>   'scheduler/enqueued': 3,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3, 
>   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 14, 23, 47, 55, 36009)}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message says unable to  retrieve ` https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do?searchType=name` can you check if the url exists and is reachable.